# Jenkins pipeline performance, Build graphs extraction

Tags: performance, jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-pipeline, email-attachments

I'm working on a Jenkins pipeline project to execute Jmeter and Robot scripts together win two stages of the node. All are working fine and I'm wondering if there is any way to extract the graphs generated by the performance plugin and attach them to the email.

This is one of the image samples [image: Responce time Summary Graph]

If there is a way extract and attach them as images (not the image link) with Jenkins pipeline email-ext commands please let me know.

Best Regards,
Muditha

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare a docker image with python, selenium python sdk and phantomjs webdriver installed.

And prepare a python script in docker image to do following things:

1. open the page includes the performance graph in headless browser phantomjs
2. find the graph from the whole page
3. use selenium/phantomjs api to take screenshot on the graph and save it

Run a docker container from this image to execute the python script, and mapping a host folder to the graph save folder in container.

After the container running, you can get the graph from the workspace of the job.

Comment: I also Tried something similar. I opened the image to download it and sent it. But I was wondering if there is a way to do it directly. Like using a Jenkins function to extract images.

Comment: Form i understand, the graph is generated by the performance plugin, also this plugin controls how to display the graph on Jenkins page.(For the source cod of Jenkins plugin, not only include java code, but also HTML part for your plugin UI) . thus Jenkins can't  supply a unify function/api to interact with graph generated by any plugin directly.

Comment: I guess the source data of the graph comes the jmeter report which should be saved   into your job's workspace,  you can look into the plugin source code to see is there any function used to generate graph from jmeter report, then you can write a similar function  and call it as you needed.

Comment: I too checked it but it looks like it's a graph generated by the plugin. If we change the parameters in the URL the graph will change. Still, we can download it as an image too.